# Can an asylum seeker with a temporary residence permit from a host country travel to other Schengen countries?

Tags: schengen, transit, permits, residency

I traveled to Schengen country illegally as ***(Asylum seeker)***, now the host country gave me a temporary residence permit, If I can work in host country, so can I work outside the host country mean in other Schengen country like Germany? Can I travel in the Schengen area after acquiring my temporary residence permit from host country?

Comment: Working in another Schengen country would be considered off-topic here whereas traveling to any other country in the Schengen Area is on-topic. I suggest you to edit out the off-topic portion of your question.

Answer (score 5):

Residence permit holders can generally travel in Schengen freely.  From the [Citizens Information site of Ireland](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_abroad/freedom_of_movement_within_the_eu/free_movement_of_people_within_the_schengen_area.html):

> If you have a valid residence permit in one Schengen country you can
>   travel to the others without needing a visa (in effect, a residence
>   permit from a Schengen country is the same as a Schengen visa).

However, asylum seekers generally may not travel or work outside the host country:

> Asylum seekers in one participating country are **not entitled to travel
>   freely** to another. They are subject to the rules set out in the Dublin
>   Convention on the country to which their application for asylum must
>   be made.

So it's going to depend on what exactly your "temporary residence permit" is.  If it has no conditions attached, you should be free to travel; if it's only until your asylum application has been processed, you may not travel.  Ask the authorities who issued it.

For what it's worth, the [europa.eu page on the Dublin II Regulation](http://europa.eu/legislation_summaries/justice_freedom_security/free_movement_of_persons_asylum_immigration/l33153_en.htm) does not mention this explicitly, but the travel ban appears to be a side effect of the rule forbidding asylum seekers from trying their luck in multiple countries.